# Ordering by multiple ACF fields

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, wordpress

I've seen a few questions similar to this but I still can't get things working so I thought I'd ask.

I have a Custom Post Type called 'Course'. This CPT has a custom field called 'date' which is either past, future or not set (null).

I am trying to write a query that hides the past courses, then shows future courses (ordered by date, soonest first) and then shows the courses where the date is not set (placeholder courses).

My plan was to add a 'placeholder_course' field to the course CPT and the date box would only appear if this was set to false. That way all of the placeholders would have a value of 1 for this field so I could sort by this to have them appear at then end, and then sort by the date to order the values in the date field correctly.

This is what I've been using:

```
  <?php
  $today = current_time('Ymd');
  $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'course',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query' => array(
      'relation' => 'OR',
      'placeholder' => array(
          'key' => 'placeholder_course',
          'compare' => '=',
          'value' => '1
      ),
      'future_dates' => array(
          'key' => 'date',
          'compare' => '>=',
          'value' => $today,
      )
    ),
    'orderby' => array(
      'placeholder' => 'ASC',
      'future_dates' => 'ASC',
    ),
    );
  ?>
```

but the ordering is still coming out muddled. I'm pretty sure I've just done something wrong in the query, can anyone shed any light please?

Comment: You have a syntax error...And `orderby` doesn't take an array with named keys.

Comment: https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/03/30/query-improvements-in-wp-4-2-orderby-and-meta_query/ seems to suggest that the named key syntax i okay in Wordpress > 4.2...

Answer (score 0):

Set up a `true/false` field for your placeholder value (if no date is set you can check on it) then the following code runs through either future dates or any post with the placeholder `true/false` value set to `true`

**UPDATE:** your'e probably gonna have to do this with 2 queries.

```
    $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'course',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'meta_key' => 'date',
            'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                    'key' => 'date', 
                    'value' => $today, 
                    'compare' => '>=',
                ),
            ), 
            'orderby'=> 'meta_value_num',
            'order' => 'ASC'
        );
$args2 = array(
            'post_type' => 'course',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                    'key' => 'placeholder_course', 
                    'value' => true, 
                    'compare' => '=',
                ),
            ), 
            'order' => 'ASC'
        );
```

Comment: Hi Mark, this does indeed pull out the future dates and the true/false set to true... but it doesn't order it as I'd hoped (with the dated events first, in date order, and then the placeholder events)

Comment: @JoeCzucha I changed the meta key field. should be fine now

Comment: sorry i made a mistake. lemme redo

Comment: your'e probably gonna have to do 2 queries

Comment: Thanks Mark, I'm keen to try and do it in a single query as I'm using the query to build a list of filters as well as output the list of courses. I'll keep playing